# Iterate over CoreData to-many relationship in deterministic order

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Is there a way to iterate over a core data relationship in deterministic order ? I don't care what the order is, and I don't want to manage it myself, I just want to be able to rely on the fact that two subsequent calls to this ordering will give me the same result (assuming no object insertion/deletion in between).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mark the relationship as ordered, that will be mapped to an `NSOrderedSet` in your `NSManagedObject` subclass. You can access the ordered set just like an array, the order will always be kept the same: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsorderedset

[image]